# Defining GPIO for LED board - Meraki MX100

Tags: openwrt, gpio, vyos

I have a Meraki MX100 that I have installed VyOS on. While otherwise perfectly functional, the one thing that I cannot seem to get working is the LED board on the front panel. I'm no developer which I'm sure is 99% of the issue here.

The LED's don't show up in /sys/class/leds/. I believe that the LED's are driven from a GPIO interface, but I don't know how to say "Hey Linux these are LED's". The Meraki MX100 is a proprietary design and information is hard to come by.

I'm including a picture of the back of the LED board. The header for the cable on the motherboard isn't notably labeled.

[image: back of led board]

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I was able to find the following entries from the make config build file in the Meraki kernel:

CONFIG_KEYBOARD_GPIO_POLLED=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_OPTIONAL_GPIOLIB=y
CONFIG_GPIOLIB=y
CONFIG_GPIO_DEVRES=y
CONFIG_GPIO_ACPI=y
CONFIG_GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP=y
CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_GPIO_ICH=y
CONFIG_GPIO_PCA953X=y
CONFIG_GPIO_PCA953X_IRQ=y
CONFIG_LEDS_GPIO=y

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but the GPIOs are configured in the Meraki kernel in a platform module file. This can be seen at https://github.com/riptidewave93/meraki-linux/blob/093132b26f2873b4e30a8c58523339ebd90f2b07/arch/x86/platform/meraki/tink.c

Comment: So you took that Thing apart what was the Trick I want to put some slower Fans in it?

Comment: @ChrisB Thank you!!! That makes my brain a bit happier and I can cross figuring that out off of my bucket list.

Comment: @Dudley I haven't touched it in a while, but the only trick I remember was having a set of screwdrivers :-)